# Mobx state tree types.function is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-state-tree

Is there a way to create Mobx store with navigate property? Something like this:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const mobxStore = useMemo(() => RootStore.create({ routeNavigate: navigate }, INITIAL_STORE), []);
```

as a result i want to get something like this:

```
.model('RootStore', {
        routeNavigate: types.function
    })
```

Because in this example routeNavigate is undefined. So i tried to add in RootStore identifier for a routeNavigate, like:

```
routeNavigate: types.frozen() or
routeNavigate: types.function
```

and it throws errors in console.

- I tried to add different identifiers to routeNavigate
- Tried to pass property in RootStore.create